# EACCES (Permission denied) in using Camera Android

Tags: android

I want to get and storage a photo from an android camera. This is the code:

```
public void avviaFotocamera(View v){
        this.launchCamera();
    }

    private void launchCamera() {
        try {
            mOutputFile = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "temp.jpg");
            Intent intentCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(mOutputFile));
            startActivityForResult(intentCamera, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }   catch (Exception e) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Si è verificato un errore durante l'acquisizione dell'immagine:\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        }
    }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                try {
                    Bitmap datiFoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),
                                      Uri.fromFile(mOutputFile));
                    saveBitmap(datiFoto);
                    mOutputFile.delete();
                }   catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Si è verificato un errore durante l'acquisizione dell'immagine:\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.show();
                }
            }
        }

    private void saveBitmap(Bitmap datiFoto) {
        try {
            //Nome del file da assegnare all'immagine
            final String fileName = "prova.jpg";
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getExternalStorageDirectory ()+fileName);
            datiFoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        }   catch (Exception e) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Si è verificato un errore durante il salvataggio dell'immagine:\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

however i get this error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /prova.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied). 
This is the manifest where i add all the required permissions:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="22"
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.android.maps.path.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

How can i fix it??

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're trying to save the file as `/prova.jpg`, which would be in the root directory of the device.  Your app can't store files there.  It appears that this line isn't working as expected:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getExternalStorageDirectory ()+fileName);
```

Perhaps try:

```
File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "prova.jpg");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
```